# Gerrit installation on CentOS doesn't work

Tags: linux, git, centos, gerrit

I have installed gerrit on my centos server, but I have a problem with the authentication. I would like to give authentication privileges for the centos users in a given group. Basically, every user in the gerrit group should have the possibility to log in with its password.

But, when I access the gerrit link, there is a redirect to gerrit:8081/login when I get the following message:

> The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization
>   header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.
>
> If the HTTP server is Apache HTTPd, check the proxy configuration
>   includes an authorization directive with the proper location, ensuring
>   it ends with '/':

Do you have any hints why this doesn't work?

The VirtualHost part of the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file looks something like this:

```
<VirtualHost gerrit:8081>
    ServerName gerrit

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location "/login/">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
    AuthBasicProvider file
      AuthUserFile /etc/passwd
      Require valid-user
    </Location>


    AllowEncodedSlashes On
       ProxyPass /r http://localhost:8081/r nocanon
</VirtualHost>
```

And the gerrit.config file:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = /repos
        canonicalWebUrl = http://freshattitude.eu:8081/
[database]
        type = mysql
        hostname = localhost
        database = gerrit
        username = gerrit
[auth]
        type = HTTP
        emailFormat = {0}@example.com
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = localhost
        smtpUser = root
[container]
        user = gerrit
        javaHome = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8081/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

Answer (score 1):

You made some mistakes. On the one hand, you have to set in `gerrit.config`

```
httpd.listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

so that Gerrit knows about the proxy in front of it.

Furthermore, your Apache vhost has to listen to a different port (at least when both services run on the same server). In fact, I'm wondering how you've been able to start both at the same time ;-)

So set an apache vhost up for port 80, not for port 8081. Then users will connect to http://freshattitude.eu/.

Finally, again in `gerrit.config`, you have to fix your `canonicalWebUrl` and remove the `:8081`, as because of you're using a proxy, this is how you tell to Gerrit what its URL towards the outside world is.

I think you should go through [Gerrit docs on reverse proxy config](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-reverseproxy.html#_apache_2_configuration) once.

Afterwards you will end up with Gerrit listening only on localhost port 8081 and apache listening to port 80 (sure, you might want to use SSL, then use the `proxy-https` variant in `gerrit.config`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration which runs and help you https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/repo-discuss/qwQxy_izXzo

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Please note that this config is not valid for Gerrit 2.6+ anymore, as "AllowEncodedSlashes On" and "ProxyPass ... nocanon" are required! Otherwise you will end up with 404 errors when opening the change screen.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Gerrit requires the authentication details to be provided in the request header when using HTTP authentication. So, when using this anonymous access is not possible. 
Because of this I changed the `Location "/login/"` to `Location "/"`, then authentication is always done before going to Gerrit. That it works and I can live with it.

This might actually be some regression bug that crept in somewhere but that how I have it working.